# Unity spriting a platform tile

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I am new to unity and I am trying to make a game with platforms.

so I have a tile, which is build from three images: right corner, left corner and the middle, and I want to make tiles in different sizes, so one would looke like for example:

`{left, middle, middle, right}`

and another:

`{left, middle, middle, middle, middle, right}`.

is that possible to make?

these are the tiles I am talking about to make more sense:

[image: tile1]

[image: tile2]

[image: tile3]

Comment: Yes, you can make them as prefabs and then instantiate them as many times as you want

Comment: @the.Legend can you please add some more detailes on how to implement it?

Comment: Do you want to make them in runtime?

Comment: you want a script to create them?or you want to do it  manually?

Comment: @MiladQasemi I want it during run time, because I want it to be random widths

Comment: @DramboHero https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hardest problem is with positioning of tiles.

Lets say your tiles have a in-game width of 1 meter.
If you place your left tile at game coordinates (0,0) you have to place your middle tile at (1,0) and end with your right tile at (2,0)

Once you can visualize this you can apply it to any location. 
Left tile at (x,y) will have a middle tile at (x+1,y) and a right tile at (x+2,y)

But what if you want to add more middle tiles?
Imagine you have a function with parameter n. n is the number of middle tiles you will need. Each time you build a middle tile you can decrease n by one. When n is 0 then you place the right tile.

some pseudocode

```
public void spawnPlatform(int n){  
 int x = random num between 1-10;  
 int y = random num between 1-10;  
 Instantiate left at coord (x,y)

 for(int i=1;i>n;i++){  
  Instantiate middle at coord (x+i,y)  

 }  

 Instantiate right at coord (x+n,y)  
}
```